# Python requests - парсинг страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

Хочу вытащить информацию со [страницы .../investidei?status=executed&currency=rub](https://bcs-express.ru/investidei?status=executed&currency=rub) и, кажется, что проблема в том, что он подгружается в реальном времени.

Получить правильный url получилось

```
parms = {'currency':'rub', 'status':'executed'}
base_url = 'https://bcs-express.ru/investidei'
page = requests.get(base_url, params=parms)
print(page.url)
```

Далее делаю

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
ideas_name_list = soup.find(class_='ideas-list')
print(ideas_name_list)
```

Но получаю результаты со страницы [.../investidei](https://bcs-express.ru/investidei)

Почему это происходит и как решить проблему?

Comment: _> Но получаю результаты со страницы .../investidei_ Как вы это смогли определить, если выше у вас напечатался правильный URL?

Comment: Посмотрел на то, что выводит print(ideas_name_list). Не увидел этого на странице /investidei?status=executed&currency=rub, но увидел на /investidei

Comment: В первом случае там работает какой-то JavaScript, который заменяет содержимое нужного вам элемента. На этапе загрузки у обоих списков одинаковое содержимое.

Comment: Более того, там идёт обращение к API. https://bcs-express.ru/webapi/api/idea?status=executed&limit=20&currency=rub - видимо, вот нужный вам список. Когда есть JSON, не нужно парсить HTML (тем более в котором нет таких данных).

Comment: Да, это именно он!! А как вы узнали о том, что идёт обращение к API. И можно ли каким то образом вытащить все данные(это только первая страница - до нажатия на Показать еще)

Comment: Открываете в браузере инструменты разработчика и переходите на вкладку "Сеть". Среди всех запросов будут и запросы к API. Чтобы понять, что происходит после нажатия на "Показать ещё", запомните последний запрос в списке, нажмите на кнопку и посмотрите, что добавилось. Там какой-то filtersorting появляется.

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался! А что лучше использовать, чтобы это все автоматизировать и не доставать каждый раз руками?